# Server hangs on shutdown

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, tomcat

I had recently started a server using /startServer.sh and everything was perfect. Suddenly, there was a power failure here and my os shut down. After booting up, when I tried running ./startServer.sh again, it hangs at:

> [INFO] Press Ctrl-C to stop the container...

As a result, I am not able to get the server started again. I really don't know the cause, but I would greatly appreciate any guidance. I have a mac osx 10.6 am using Tomcat and MySQL (running as a daemon). Thanks!

Comment: Paste your `startServer.sh` into pastbin and insert link here. Also post the entire output when running `./startServer.sh`. Did you check to see it is already running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: when I restarted my mac, my IP address changed. So I had to modify pom.xml to point to the new ip address. Which means that the server was always running- its just that I was checking out the wrong IP address. Thanks for your help, and sorry for the any wasted.

Comment: Sweet when you figure it out on your own, eh ??? +1 !!!

Comment: haha, yeah! you end up feeling quite silly once you figure it out too.